# Shell script to transfer files

Tags: linux, shell, passwords, transfer

I have a shell script that starts a For loop, reads from a text file with hostnames, and uses SCP to transfer files to each host. It's been very useful but what is the best way to deal with the password prompt? The only authentication I was given to the servers were a username and password.

As of now, I've had to input my password for each server. It's been duoable since the server count is low but I'd like to have a better solution in the future. Any help/suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most servers also support publickey authentication. [Generate a keypair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) on your local host, then copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa_pub` to remote host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or append to it if it already exists). Deal with the keyphrase locking your secret key by using `ssh-agent`.

Comment: A good sample for this, it's https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of interactive action you can use [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) scripts. You can easily define a remote call where you expect for a especific string (f.e "username:") and then send the known password.